# How can I send data from a NodeMCU ESP32 to Firebase using Micropython

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, esp32, micropython

I'm trying to get sensor data from an ESP32 (Devkit V1) to Firebase Realtime Database. I saw some tutorials but they were all using Arduino code, whereas I am running Micropython code on the ESP32 because I was having issues with Arduino and I am more experienced in Python.

Could someone help me with getting the data to Firebase, using Micropython.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you need create account in firebase. Using firebase real time database. After you get credentials. After you type a code similar this:

```
import urequests
import ujson
import network

# Your WiFi credentials
WIFI_SSID = "YourWiFiSSID"
WIFI_PASSWORD = "YourWiFiPassword"

# Firebase project credentials
FIREBASE_URL = "https://your-project-id.firebaseio.com"
SECRET_KEY = "YourFirebaseSecretKey"

def connect_wifi():
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    if not wlan.isconnected():
        print("Connecting to WiFi...")
        wlan.connect(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD)
        while not wlan.isconnected():
            pass
    print("WiFi Connected")
    print("IP:", wlan.ifconfig()[0])

def send_to_firebase(data):
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + SECRET_KEY
    }
    url = FIREBASE_URL + "/your-collection.json"  # Change 'your-collection' to your Firebase collection

    response = urequests.post(url, data=ujson.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    print("Firebase Response:", response.text)
    response.close()

sensor_data = {
    "temperature": 25.5,
    "humidity": 60
}

connect_wifi()
send_to_firebase(sensor_data)
```

Maybe you need install some libs in Arduino IDE with: json, wifi, etc.